# Android activity with multiple repeating backgrounds

Tags: android

I'm still new to android and i'm having trouble creating a layout with two backgrounds that tile in the x direction but not y.

I've mocked up what I'm trying to create here...

http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/6008/cnbackground.png

So the top section repeats horizontally, then there's a flat creen section in the middle in which I will center my content, then there's some horizontally repeating grass along the bottom.

Has anyone tried to do anything like this before?

Jon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a good simple tutorial on the repeated background image part:

http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html

As far as the layout, I'd go with a RelativeLayout as my main parent layout, and then you'll have three sub-layouts to represent the top, middle, and bottom sections.  Use android:layout_alignParentTop on the top layout, android:layout_alignParentBottom on the bottom, and the middle content layout should have the attributes android:layout_above and android:layout_below set to the @+id's of the bottom and top (respectively).

Comment: I had hoped to be able to just add 2 backgrounds to the main activity, without having to actually divide the screen into 3 but I'm guessing you can only have one android:background attribute on a tag. Also, that article only mentions 3 tileModes repeat, mirror, or clamp and doesn't say how to get something to tile only horizontally. In css I would do this by setting {background-repeat:repeat-x;}

Comment: Yep...but this ain't html/css, so you have to hack around the things you would expect to be there that aren't.  Since you can't do it via repeat-x, I would make the top/bottom layouts have a layout_height of wrap_content, and give them a child ImageView instead of a background.  The ImageView's src can be your @drawable that uses the bitmap element with tileMode = repeat.  That way, everything stays dynamically sized anyway (which is clearly the intention of the Android gods)

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic repeat-x by using a layer-list as the drawable. You tile bitmap image both x and y and then use an offset solid shape to fill over the repeated y images. Isn't perfect, but will do the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item>
  <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
 </item>
 <item android:top="60dp">
  <shape >
   <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
  </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```